# Create links from String results after SQL search

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, hyperlink, sql-search

I have successfuly searched my DB table for what i want and passed it into a DataTable (dt).
The idea is that i want (after the search) to redirect someone to the result page he likes.

So if he Searches for example "Michael"  , i'd like to show him , the name Michael as a link , and if he presses it redirect him to his page, which is made by ~/Default.aspx?Email="+ id (id also results after the search and is casted to string).

My Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable PassRecord = new DataTable();


            String str = "select First_Name,Surname,id from ID where (First_Name like '%'+ @search +'%' ) OR (Surname like '%'+ @search +'%') OR (Email_Account like '%'+ @search +'%')";


            SqlCommand Srch = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            Srch.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;



            con.Open();
            Srch.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = Srch;


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dt);



            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {


                var field = dr["First_Name"].ToString();
                Response.Write(field);
                Response.Write("<br/>");
            }
```

As u understand i want to create a link redirecting to the users profile after the search.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in Advance !!!

Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer using

```
var field = "<a href='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx?Email=" + dr["id"]) + "'>" + (dr["First_Name"] + "").ToString() + "</a>";
```

It's mainly as @Mikhail Timofeev said but with tiny modification.

***Explanation*** :

`Page.ResolveUrl`: ensure to refers relatively to where user is at in your website's tree so it can be use by client (Browser) (See [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl(v=vs.110).aspx)).

`dr["First_Name"] + ""` is prefered, for me, in case a DBNull.Value may comes here and may fails if it happens.

Comment: well both got me to the next step but dr["First_Name"] + "" is not failing at Null, which now is my new problem, cause when it gets to the default users page the session is null :p

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
var field = "<a href='/Default.aspx?Email="+dr["id"]+"'>"+ dr["First_Name"].ToString()+"</a>";
```